# QML progress bar is NOT showing up on UI

Tags: qt, qml, progress-bar, qtquickcontrols

I have this QML progress bar:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 as QQC20

Item {
    QQC20.ProgressBar {
        id: progressbar_id
        visible: false // even if "true", the progress bar does NOT show up on UI
        from: editorScene.progressbarMin
        to: editorScene.progressbarMax
        value: editorScene.progressbarVal

        onValueChanged: {
            console.log("Progressbar value changed: ", progressbar_id.value)
        }
        onVisibleChanged: {
            console.log("Progressbar visibility chanaged: ", progressbar_id.visible)
        }
    }
}
```

I can confirm that the progress bar value and visibility are changed by the methods `onValueChanged` and `onVisibleChanged`.

However, the problem is that the progress bar does NOT show up on the UI! How can I actually show the progress bar on the UI? Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: `Item` does not declare `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight`, so wherever you use your QML file, you must make sure it is given width & height, and on top of that you should put `anchors.fill: parent` in `QQC20.ProgressBar` to make it fill all space the outer `Item` gets. Or if possible you could just get rid of the outer `Item`

Comment: @Amfasis I'm not finding that to be an error... For me, `ProgressBar` automatically  sets a width and height. I'm on a  MacOS, not sure if that changes anything...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now, all you're doing is creating a QML type which you can use as part of your API. To actually *see* it, you need to create an instance of it under a [`ApplicationWindow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html) or [`Window`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html) (or anything else equivalent, e.g. [`Canvas`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html) or Felgo's [`GameWindow`](https://felgo.com/doc/felgo-gamewindow/)).

There are two ways you can accomplish this. You can

1. Directly add your item as a child of a window.
2. Put your item in a separate file, and create an instance of *that* file under a window.

## Lé Code

#### Method 1: Directly Adding as Child

Directly insert your codeblock as a child of an `ApplicationWindow`.

```
// Main.qml
import QtQuick 2.0             // for `Item`
import QtQuick.Window 2.0      // for `ApplicationWindow`
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0    // as QQC20 // no need to label a namespace unless disambiguation is necessary

ApplicationWindow {

    width: 480   // set the dimensions of the application window
    height: 320
    
    // here's your item
    Item {
        anchors.centerIn: parent   // place in centre of window
        
        ProgressBar {
            id: progressbar_id
            
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter // horizontally align the progress bar
            
            from: 0    // don't know what editorScene is
            to: 100    // so I'm using raw values
            value: 5
    
            onValueChanged: {
                console.log("Progressbar value changed: ", progressbar_id.value)
            }
            onVisibleChanged: {
                // side note: I'm not getting any output from this handler
                console.log("Progressbar visibility chanaged: ", progressbar_id.visible)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // provide user-interaction for changing progress bar's value
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent            // clicking anywhere on the background
        onClicked: progressbar_id.value += 5;   // increments the progress bar
                                                // and triggers onValueChanged
    }
}
```

#### Method 2: Using a Separate File

Save your item into a new qml file.

```
// MyProgressBar.qml
import QtQuick 2.0              // for `Item`
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0     // for `ProgressBar`

// here is your item, it has grown up to be in a file of its own 
Item {

    property alias value: progressbar_id.value  // for user-interaction

    ProgressBar {
        id: progressbar_id
        
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter  // centre horizontally
        
        from: 0
        to: 100
        value: 5

        onValueChanged: {
            console.log("Progressbar value changed: ", progressbar_id.value)
        }
        onVisibleChanged: {
            console.log("Progressbar visibility chanaged: ", progressbar_id.visible)
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>Note that you still need the `import` statements.</sup>

Then call it from a window in `Main.qml`. We'll use an `ApplicationWindow` here.

```
// Main.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0    // for `ApplicationWindow`

// import "relative/path/to/progressbar"  // use this if MyProgressBar.qml is not in the same folder as Main.qml

ApplicationWindow {

    width: 480
    height: 320
    
    MyProgressBar {
         id: progressbar_id
    }
    
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: progressbar_id.value += 5;
    }
}
```

If your qml files aren't in the same directory, make sure you add an `import "relative/path"` at the top of the `Main.qml` file among the other import statements.

For example, if

- Your Qml project is in `/Users/Lorem/Project`,
- The full path to your `Main.qml` is `/Users/Lorem/Project/qml/Main.qml`, and
- The full path to your `MyProgressBar.qml` is `/Users/Lorem/Project/qml/myControls/MyProgressBar.qml`...

Then use `import "myControls"` in `Main.qml` to import the items from the `myControls` subdirectory. Remember, you only need to import the directory, not the file itself.

## Result

This is what the result resembles when I run it from a macOS.

At startup.

[image: At startup.]

After 3 clicks on the background.

[image: After 3 clicks on the background.]

There is also console/debug output after each click:

```
Progressbar value changed: 10
Progressbar value changed: 15
Progressbar value changed: 20
```

Comment: When implementing method 2, I receive an error saying: `MyProgressBar is not a type`

Comment: Are they in the same folder? If not, remember to import the folder in your `Main.qml` or wherever you use it. And make sure you use whatever you name the file with. E.g. if you named the file `MySuperAwesomeProgressBar.qml`, use `MySuperAwesomeProgressBar { id: progress_bar }`. Other than that, I can't guess what's causing your error.

Comment: Thanks! It got resolved. I just had to add this statement to my `qml.qrc` file: `<file alias="MyProgressBar.qml">qml/MyProgressBar.qml</file>` since my file was inside a subdirectory named `qml`

Comment: Ah ok. I think `import qml` would've done it as well. But `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` whatever works for you.