# Feeding repeater an array of objects

Tags: qt, qml

I have written a code that parses a JSON file and saves data in an array of object struct like below:

```
        /*DataModel.qml*/
        Item {
           id: dataModel

           property var forecastData: []

           function updateForecastFromJson(parsedJSONData) {
              var index = 0
              for(;index < 5; ++index) {
                var temp = {
                   'temp_min': parsedJSONData.list[index].main.temp_min,
                   'temp_max': parsedJSONData.list[index].main.temp_max,
                   'weatherIconUrl': parsedJSONData.list[index].main.url,
                   'weatherCondition': parsedJSONData.list[index].main.condition,
                   'time': parsedJSONData.list[index].main.time
              }

              dataModel.forecastData.push(temp)
           }
        }
```

the *DataModel.qml* is a singlton and I use it in a repeater like below to display data:

```
/*main.qml*/ 
Window { 
Grid {
   id: bottomGrid  
   Repeater {
       model: [
         { day: DataModel.forecastData[0].time, high: 
           DataModel.forecastData[0].temp_max, low: 
           DataModel.forecastData[0].temp_min, sourceIcon: 
           DataModel.forecastData[0].weatherIconUrl },
         { day: DataModel.forecastData[1].time, high: 
           DataModel.forecastData[1].temp_max, low: 
           DataModel.forecastData[1].temp_min, sourceIcon: 
           DataModel.forecastData[1].weatherIconUrl },
         { day: DataModel.forecastData[2].time, high: 
           DataModel.forecastData[2].temp_max, low: 
           DataModel.forecastData[2].temp_min, sourceIcon: 
           DataModel.forecastData[2].weatherIconUrl },
         { day: DataModel.forecastData[3].time, high: 
           DataModel.forecastData[3].temp_max, low: 
           DataModel.forecastData[3].temp_min, sourceIcon: 
           DataModel.forecastData[3].weatherIconUrl },
         { day: DataModel.forecastData[4].time, high: 
           DataModel.forecastData[4].temp_max, low: 
           DataModel.forecastData[4].temp_min, sourceIcon: 
           DataModel.forecastData[4].weatherIconUrl }
      ]

      Column {
         width: bottomGrid.width / 5
         spacing: dp(5)

         Image {
            source: modelData.sourceIcon
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            sourceSize: dp(20)
         }

         Item {
            width: 1
            height: dp(5)
         }

         AppText {
            text: modelData.high
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            font.pixelSize: sp(14)
        }

        AppText {
           text: modelData.low
           color: "#aaffffff"
           anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
           font.pixelSize: sp(14)
        }

        Item {
           width: 1
           height: dp(5)
        }

        AppText {
          text: modelData.day
          anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
          font.pixelSize: sp(14)
        }
     }
  }
}
```

but, when the repeater about to display a series of data,
nothing will be shown and I've got in output this :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined

I have checked if data is parsed properly several times and I'm sure that data is stored in an array of object properly. where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please provide ALL the appropriate code. Maybe someone will want to run that and test. It is not clear from your example what is `dataModel` what is `DataModel` and where do you access `time` property.

Comment: Your first snippet doesn't seem to be valid Qml/JS syntax. Did you mean to wrap `Component.onCompleted` around the js code?

Comment: @folibis I can't put all the codes here because it's a bunch of code lines. but I try to make it clear here

Comment: @TrebuchetMS I've just edited my question, I hope it's clear now ;)

Comment: Hi again, you've declared `int index = 0`. I believe there's no `int` type in js (you probably meant to use `var`). You're also missing a } bracket. Regarding your error, you might be getting it when your qml is instantiated. Whether you get the error or not may depend on *when* you call `updateForecastFromJson`.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS the thing is, I haven't had any compile error and it happens in runtime, this error will be shown in the output when repeater wants to show data of DataModel.

Comment: Umm... okay. Now that I'm looking at your code again.  You don't seem to have a Window or anything around the Repeater in main.qml. Relevant SO post? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314110/qml-progress-bar-is-not-showing-up-on-ui

Comment: @TrebuchetMS first of all, I'd like to thank you for your help. As this code is just excerpt of entire code I didn't rewrite the basic items here. Anyway, I edit the excerpt code again and put them in the code for more clearance ;) .

Comment: @folibis any idea?

Comment: You have to check that DataModel.forecastData contains at least 5 elements at the time of Repeater initialization. It looks that Repeater initializes first and so DataModel.forecastData contains no data at this moment.

Comment: @folibis that's right, but how can I make the repeater aware of new data in DataModel.forecastData. I'm literally sure that DataModel.forecastData is filled during the runtime.

Comment: first of all I see this way as you do is very unsafe and breaks MVC as well as the declarative style of QML. You have to provide model to the Repeater and  when it will be ready the Repeater should rearrange its items according to the model.

Comment: could you please do me a favor and provide more details about what you say?